# $_session['name'] doesn't echo a name but instead echo the number zero

Tags: php, session

I have the a problem with my current script. I want it to echo the variable $_SESSION['name'] and the result should be displaying the name. Instead, it just displays the number zero, instead of the name. Though my Database is filled with several users and usernames, it refuses to display any name.

```
<?php

ob_start();
$host="127.0.0.1"; // Host name 
$username="admin"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$myusername=$_POST['id']; 
$password=$_POST['password'];
$mypassword=md5($password);
$myname = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM $tbl_name WHERE id = $myusername");
if (!$myname) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "plaza.php"
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['password'] = $mypassword;
$_SESSION['name'] = $myname;
header("location:plaza.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password, <a href='index.php'>click here</a> return";
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

//

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])){
    header("location:index.php");
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
        </div>
        <div id="main_container">
            <div id="module_0">
                <h1>Welkom <?php
                             echo $_SESSION['name'];
                            ?>
                <form action="logout.php">
                    <input type="submit" value="Uitloggen"/>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="module_1">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque id lacus nec tortor euismod ultrices vehicula vitae tellus. Aliquam consectetur risus suscipit auctor placerat. Nunc nec imperdiet odio. Integer eu dui ut nisi dictum varius in vitae erat. Duis porta, lorem nec volutpat vulputate, nulla elit pretium tellus, vel iaculis purus lacus et lectus. Ut porttitor odio vel tempor varius. Nam id eros sed risus tincidunt pharetra. Ut ligula diam, elementum et facilisis ut, lobortis sit amet leo.
            </div>
            <div id="module_2">
            </div>
            <div id="module_3">
            </div>
            <div id="module_4">
            </div>
            <div id="module_5">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with the script, why it shows the number 0, instead of a name?

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection via `$_POST['id']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of the code:

```
$myname = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM $tbl_name WHERE id = $myusername");
if (!$myname) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
```

You should change it to:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM $tbl_name WHERE id = $myusername");
$arr = mysql_fetch_array($res);
$myname = $arr['username'];
if (!$myname) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Just little bug - you are using mysql and mysqli together.

Comment: So, please mark my answer as solution.

Comment: Had to wait a minute ^^

Comment: If the username is empty, or zero, or generally speaking - `falsy`, it will exit, but mysql_error() won't return any error

Answer (score 3):

$myname is a [resource](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) and not the data from the database. You should use [mysql_fetch_row](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_row)

Answer (score -1):

$myname is a variable type and you need to use either mysql_fetch_array() or mysql_fetch_row()
 fetch data from database then store in session variable as $_SESSION['name']..